# Cannot find draggable attribute in Cypress

Tags: angularjs, draggable, cypress

How can I get 'draggable' property of AngularJS in Cypress as Cypress can not find draggable property and "should('have.attr','draggable')" returns an error?

Comment: can you paste the html of the element you are trying to check for draggable?

Comment: <div ui-draggable="abc" drag="def" class="ghi" ng-if="Style == 'bubble'" ng-click="blabla" draggable="true">......... js(cypress) code: cy.get(".ghi").should('have.attr','draggable')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the html provided in the comment, can you try this to check if it works?

`cy.get('div[ui-draggable="abd"]')`

or

`cy.get('div[draggable="true"]')`

Comment: Actually my app has 'ui-draggable' in all the respective divs but I want to drag only those that have date value greater-equal to today's date. So the first one won't be helpful. I tried the second one. But that too didn't work as Cypress could not find the 'draggable' attribute as it does not show up in the 'div' at the time when the 'get' command runs.

Comment: You can use whatever combination of attributes and selectors inside the get, use what suits your needs. Related to the element not there on load, you can wait for it by using cy.get('whatever selector').should('be.visible'). Visible or present, can't remember now, check the official docs